# Can run empty/blank aspdotnet core web api's : An error occurred attempting to determine the process id of dotnet.exe

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, iis-10

Why cant i debug my project on iis express server? i always get the following error :An error occurred attempting to determine the process id of dotnet.exe which is hosting your application. One or more error occured

[error when running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5SXK.png)

I got tis error for 2 weeks now and have not been able to solve this. I have reinstalled visual studio multiple time, iis server and even reinstalled windows completely.
but still no change. Other solution like setting up the ssl certificat also dont work.

I use a dell precision 7510 with windows 10 enterprise with endpoint security (its a computer from work)

If anyone knows an answer 
thx

Comment: show your .json files in the properties folder if you could and your startup.cs/program.cs

Comment: this I have seen is in a form similar is a config issue or a versioning issue with dotnet. Which version of VS do you have and are you up to date with dotnet?

Comment: Yes i am running the latest dotnet versions. And i am using vs 2017